# disadvantages of marquee tag

Tags: html, marquee

Well it's evil, fine.

But what's evil in it?

- all browsers support it?
- which aspx asp.net controls can I not use in this tag?

Why not use the tag?

Comment: The wikipedia artcle covers this quite nicely http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> all browser support it?

No, although support is annoyingly broad.

> can/ cannot use what controls in the taag

Can you rephrase this. I think I can decrypt the meaning of 'taag', but the words don't form a sentence.

> why not to use the tag?

First and foremost, on a purely practical front — it makes text scroll.

Scrolling text is an excellent way to display a large amount of information in a small place, non-interactively. This makes it rather good for things like the "What stations this train will stop at" display that I get to look at on my commute.

A web page, however, is typically viewed in a relatively large display by a single person, who has a mouse, trackpad or other way to indicate when they have finished reading whatever is displayed. This means they do not have to wait for the start of the text, the text will not move faster then they can read properly, and the text will not move more slowly then they are comfortable with. Additionally, if they are trying to read something else that is near the scrolling text, they won't be constantly distracted by the movement in the corner of their eye.

Aside from that. It isn't yet standardized, and the closest it appears it will ever come is to be marked as [obsolete](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html) by HTML 5.

Comment: No idea. If I did have to use ASP.NET for some reason, I'd avoid WebForms. I've seen too many people have too much trouble trying to get them to output sane markup.

Answer (score 6):

- It's annoying.
- It's not standard.
- Not all browsers support it.
- It's annoying.

Comment: +1.  Wrong order.  "It's annoying" should be first.

Comment: I thought of another reason.  "Who actually reads the whole thing?"

Comment: @S.Lott - of course, it also makes your eyes bleed, but that's too obvious to add.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons against using marquee come mostly from usability and design reasons. It draws the user's attention needlessly, makes the text harder to read, and makes your site look sloppy.