# Marquee text sliding to center of div

Tags: html

I have the following marquee:

`<div id="tip"><marquee loop="1" direction="right" behavior="slide">Text</marquee></div>`

The above code moves the text from left to right and stops at right edge of div. Is there a way to force it to stop in center of div? I can't use paddings because the text is random and doesn't have a fixed length.

current behavior:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 >      >      >      >      >      >       >      >      >          Text
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My desired behavior:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    >    >     >    >     >     >   Text
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: emm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855252/disadvantages-of-marquee-tag

Comment: @Tim I know, but my customer want it

Comment: can't you use javascript instead? http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would not advice you to use marquee but if you really want to, then you can do this to get your desired effect

```
<div id="tip">
<div class="stop">
<marquee loop="1" direction="right" behavior="slide">Text</marquee>
</div>
</div>
```

*css*

```
.stop{width:*your choice*;}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to type is in plain html

marquee loop="1" direction="right" behavior="slide">center Text /center /marquee

you do not need to know css and be sure to include center tags inbetween the marquee tags.
have fun!!

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class="name"><marquee behavior="slide" direction="right" scrollamount="10">Sudhanshu raj</marquee></div>
```

---

```
/*This is use to set the marquee at particular position*/
CSS:-
.name {

    width: 53%;
}
```