# video name alignment not proper after marquee slide

Tags: html, css

I am using below code to display title marquee, when title is small in length than it is display as shown in image , and when title is large in lenthgh than it display properly from left side, as left aligned,

**1st issue :** is that video name should stop after marquee at left

**2nd issue :** some times after marquee I am not able to see text at all

for 2nd issue i tried to increase `scrollamount`, but still having same problem ,where I am wrong?

```
<div class="span8" style=" padding-left: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px; display:block; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap; color:#353535; overflow:hidden; width:95%;font-size:15px;">
<?php echo '<marquee loop="1" scrollamount="15" behavior="slide" direction="right">' .  stripslashes(_cut($video->title, 280)); ?> - <?php echo time_ago($video->date) . "</marquee>"?>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: you got css for that?

Comment: check this > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208662/marquee-text-sliding-to-center-of-div

Comment: @SunilKumar I referred above link , but I already have width element assigned for div `width: 95%`, div of marquee

Comment: @BIW I have this css for div in which marquee is there ,`padding-left: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px; display:block; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap; color:#353535; overflow:hidden; width:95%;font-size:15px;"`

Comment: For future readers it's probably best to add the code to your question by editing it, so they get the full story straight away.

Comment: Yes pl. create some demo for people to help you out. You can create it in either [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [Codepen](http://codepen.io/)